# IOCTL: invalid argument for HDIO_GET_IDENTITY

Tags: c, linux, centos, hard-drive, ioctl

I wrote a program to get the details of hard disk drive using `HDIO_ ioctl calls`.

For writing program, I'm referring [`Documentation/ioctl/hdio.txt`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ioctl/hdio.txt) in kernel source(2.6.32).

Here is my main part of code:

```
unsigned char driveid[512];
fd = open("/dev/sda", O_RDONLY);  // validated fd.
retval = ioctl(fd, HDIO_GET_IDENTITY, &driveid);
if(retval < 0) {
            perror("ioctl(HDIO_GET_IDENTITY)");
            exit(3);
}
```

When I run(as root) the above code, I got below error:

```
ioctl(HDIO_GET_IDENTITY): Invalid argument
```

What is the wrong in the program?
Why I'm getting error?

**Additional Info**: OS: `CentOS-6.5`, kernel version: `2.6.32`, IA:`x86_64` (running on VMware).

Answer (score 1):

the HDIO_GET_IDENTITY `ioctl()` doesn`t take a raw character buffer as its 3rd argument.

it uses a struct defined in `linux/hdreg.h`.

```
struct hd_driveid  driveid; 
fd = open("/dev/sda", O_RDONLY);  // validated fd.
retval = ioctl(fd, HDIO_GET_IDENTITY, &driveid);
if(retval < 0) {
            perror("ioctl(HDIO_GET_IDENTITY)");
            exit(3);
}
```

this way it should work. Be aware that it only works for IDE/SATA drives, SCSI is not supported.
has 
if you are wondering on how to get the information after the command `ioctl()` has returned succesfully, I suggest going through

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/hdreg.h?v=2.6.36